# lighttpd SSL - empty website in firefox/chrome but working in IE/edge

Tags: lighttpd, lets-encrypt

The certificate of our website was renewed (with letsencrypt) some days ago without checking for funcionality. Customers now complained about not working website so I checked it again and found out that the site (https://support.acam.at) is working in IE and edge but not in Firefox or Chrome. In Chrome I get the "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" message, Firefox just says (in german:)

```
"Beim Verbinden mit support.acam.at trat ein Fehler auf.
Die Website kann nicht angezeigt werden, da die Authentizität der erhaltenen Daten nicht verifiziert werden konnte.
Kontaktieren Sie bitte den Inhaber der Website, um ihn über dieses Problem zu informieren."
```

Starting the same server with apache2 works fine but we need lighttpd for internal purposes. SSL checker (https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=support.acam.at) states everything ok. lighttpd must only display a pure HTML page for testing...

lighttpd -v command shows:

```
lighttpd/1.4.45 (ssl) - a light and fast webserver
Build-Date: Feb  6 2018 12:41:51
```

Also the OS is update2date. Are there any tips how we can fix this issue? Any ideas why? Browser cache was cleared and connectiong from mobile phone did also not work...

Comment: if I disable the SSL configuration the site works as expected - in any browser...
maybe problem in SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

[Link to Bug #2912](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lighttpd/+bug/1800605)

The problem was a bug with openssl. 
After updating the OS to the latest version (disco) everything worked fine again!
You need to update the OS because otherwise the latest supported version of lighttpd is 1.4.45...